# how to have listview row colour to change based on data in the row

Tags: asp.net, listview

I followed this question [stuck on changing each row color during run-time in listview in asp.net based on database entries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5440225/447362)  and tried to do the same in VB but i am getting some unexplained errors, like Object reference not set to an instance of an object
 most likely for this row =>
Dim cell As HtmlTableRow = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("MainTableRow"), mlTableRow)

Please let me know if there is any better way / correct way to do this in VB?

```
Protected Sub ListView2_ItemDataBound1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) _
Handles ListView2.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
        Dim dataitem As ListViewDataItem = DirectCast(e.Item, ListViewDataItem)
        Dim mstorename As String = DataBinder.Eval(dataitem.DataItem, "Store")
        If mstorename = "A1" Then
            Dim cell As HtmlTableRow = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("MainTableRow"), mlTableRow)
            cell.BgColor = #E0E0E0
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Many thanks for your help.

dk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this to work, you must ensure that you provide `MainTableRow` id to `tr` element and mark it as `runat="server"` i.e. make sure that your mark-up (html) is something like

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <tr id="MainTableRow" runat="server">
   ...
```

A different (and IMO, simpler) approach will be using data-binding expressions. For example, in your markup, use

```
<ItemTemplate>
       <tr class='<%# GetRowStyle(Container.DataItem) #>'>
```

And in code-behind, have a protected function to provide CSS class based on data (a example c# function will be)

```
protected string GetRowStyle(object item)
{
   var store = DataBinder.Eval(item, "Store");
   if (store == "A1")
   {
      return "altRow";
   }
   else
   {
     return "row";
   }
}
```

And lastly, define those css classes (row, altRow) as per your needs.

Answer (score 2):

and without any code behind at all.

I just added another field to the SQL called status
for example

```
select given, surname, case when owing > 1000 then 'Behind' else 'OK' end as Status from cust
```

then in the page

```
                <ItemTemplate>
                <tr class='<%# Eval("Status") %>' style="">
```

and

```
    <style type="text/css">

    .behind
    {    
         font-style :italic ;
         color: black  ;
    }
    .ok
    {    
         color: grey  ;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but if anyone looking for inline without css (like I was) here is my solution:

The db column 'Priority' contains 0,1,2, etc.. and i want to color my list rows red,blue,green according to those :

```
<ItemTemplate>
            <div style='<%# color:" + mylistof_PRIORITYCOLORS[Convert.ToInt16(Eval("Priority"))] %>'>
```

and your list defined

```
public static List<string> mylistof_PRIORITYCOLORS = new List<string> { "Red", "Blue", "Green" };
```